# check sentence against vocabulary

Tags: python, nltk

I want to get 50 most common words from a corpus and then check if this words are present in the sentences. I want to iterate through all sentences and print vector (0 if word is in the sentence and 1 if not). I wrote this code, but it is showing only 0 (false). Any ideas?

```
import nltk
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import brown


news = brown.words(categories='news') 
news_sents = brown.sents(categories='news')

fdist = FreqDist(w.lower() for w in news) 
word_features = list(fdist.values())[:50]

num_sents = len(news.sents(fileid))

for i in range(num_sents):
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features[word] = int(word in news_sents[i])
print(features)
```

Comment: Did you check the content of word_features? Because to me it looks like they contain the word frequencies, not the words themselves. Try `fdist.most_common(50)` and extract the words from there.

Comment: I have tried, but can not find any way to extract only words. Tried to search in nltk documentation, but not success.

Comment: `most_common()` returns a list of tuples, with some basic python knowledge, you can extract the desired element of each tuple. Try something like`word_features = [word for word, _ in fdist.most_common(50)]`